# why am i getting java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol?

Tags: java, php, html, mysql

the website that im hosting off of is 000webhost.com

this is in the console that is the error,

```
 java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: OxidePKz.net63.net/checkvote.php?   username=oxide
 at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

and this is my check vote page code

```
   <?php
$con = mysql_connect("mysql1.000webhost.com", "a5999082_oxidepk", "(put in right passcode)");
if (!$con) {
    die("Could not connect to database: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("DATABASE_NAME", $con);
$username = mysql_escape_string($_GET['username']);
if (isset($_GET['username'])) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `votes` where username = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if($row['username'] == $username) {
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM `votes` where username = '$username'");
        echo "true";
    } else {
        echo "false";
    }
}
```

i made a my admin php thing with the table name votes
and this is the call back page

```
    $rspscoding = gethostbyname("http://www.oxidepkz.net63.net");
    if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $rspscoding) {
        $con = mysql_connect("mysql1.000webhost.com", "a5999082_oxidepk", "(put in right passcode)");
        if (!$con) {
            die("Could not connect to database: " . mysql_error());
        }
        mysql_select_db("DATABASE_NAME", $con);
        $username = mysql_escape_string($_GET['username']);
        if (isset($_GET['username'])) {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `votes` (username) VALUES ('$username')") or die(mysql_error());  
        }
        mysql_close($con);
}
```

Comment: sql injection **and** `mysql_` functions in the same code... ouch

Comment: You need to put a protocol; try putting `http://` before the URL.

Comment: where .... pleas be more specific..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things;

1. I'm wonderinhg why you are getting back a java exception from a php application
2. Next  gethostbyname("http://www.oxidepkz.net63.vote.html") does NOT take a URL, it takes a hostname like "www.oxidepkz.net63.com" for example according to:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php
3. Finally, your URL is malformed since there is no ending slash after the domain name.
   "http://www.oxidepkz.net63.vote.html" will not work in any browser
   Did it get truncated, perhaps?

Comment: Weird in that I don't see anything in that code that calls your script's url. Does it work by just visiting the url ? The console that you read the error from is some tool provided by the host? It may be throwing an unrelated error since it's running java. Because what the error means is that something tried to make a url object in Java that didn't have a protocol (i.e no http:// ftp:// etc).

Comment: thanks for the help i figured it out, it was in my code not the php or the html for future refrence,

Comment: ah, glad you found it :)